# Tricks for writing clean code

Tags: python, coding-style

Heres a python code

```
def issubset(a,b): i=0
 j=0
 while i < len(a):
        c = False
        while j < len(b):
            if a[i] == b[j]:
                c = True
                j = j+1 
            if c:
                c = False
            else:
                return False 
        j=0
        i = i+1
 return True
```

There are
 some tricks that can make the above code cleaner.

```
def issubset(a, b):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        c = False
        for j in range(len(b)):
            c = c or a[i]==b[j]
            if c:
                c = False
            else:
                return False
    return True
```

Can it be cleaner?
I guess there are some tricks like

```
if condition:
   <var> = True
```

can replace with

```
<var> = <var> or condition
```

or
    if tempokay ==False:
        okay = False
can replace with

```
okay = okay and tempokay
```

Is there any more tricks like this?

Comment: this might be better suited for codereview.stackexchange

Comment: @dm03514 maybe not because it doesn't seem to work

Comment: `all(x in b for x in a)` or better `set(a).issubset(b)`.

Answer (score 4):

it looks like you are using indexes in your loop to access array members.  This is not pythonic.

Just loop through your array

```
for member in your_list:
   for member_two in second_list:
      pass
```

Comment: Thank you! How about those if statement? it looks cumbersom